# Wifi Direct Connection in Unity3D for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-wifi

How to connect two android devices for android using wifi direct in unity.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. Where are you in your process? Any code you can share? Things you have tried already? I'm assuming you're using the Pro version? That should give you access to sockets.

Comment: THanks for your reply Bart..I have made a single player game in unity and its working fine .I have converted it in android..I have seen its working fine in the device as well...Yes i have pro version of unity...Actully i don't know how to make multiplayer game for andriod using wifi direct..I want any tutorial or help regarding this..If you have any ...It would be your highness.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) tutorial to learn how to create a Wi-Fi direct application.

To help you understand some fundamental Android APIs and coding practices, a variety of sample code is available from the Android SDK Manager.There is code for wifi-direct file transfer (WiFiDirectDemo).

you can find the source code for all samples at this location:

sdk/samples/android-version/

Comment: Thanks man mridul for your reply...I actually know how to make wifi connection in android using eclipse.But i want to do the same functionality in the Unity..How can i do this in unity???  is there any way out..??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39690512/12130325

This is a plugin which cost 20-30$

If you want to make it with a free plugin you can try this one :https://github.com/saltyJeff/UnityWifiDirect

It works pretty well too. And it has only Wi-Fi Direct in it. No other things like TCP / mySQL server, etc...