# Unity3d WIfi direct (P2P) android support

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, p2p, wifi-direct

I am trying to figure out how to make game which will work only locally using Wifi Direct without any internet access.

The concept is very simple. It will be some kind of **presentation** so I need to have **one master/host** device and **other** connected **devices** will be **slaves/clients**. When I **press button** on master/host than should be **changed only one value** (string or int) **in all slaves/clients devices.**
With support of 20-40 connected devices in same time.

**I have Tried:**

1. UNet - it works only if it is connected to some router with use of local IP's but it does not support Wifi direct communication.
2. I have tried to find some plugins but I cannot decide which to choose or get information about support of Wifi direct.
3. I tried to find some other solution like Bluetooth but it supports only 4-13 connected devices at same time but I need to he connected around 20-40 devices in same time.

**List of plugins I have found:**

1. Forge Networking  - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38344

   1.1 I do not know if this supports a feature i required.
2. WifiDirect Plugin - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/50112

   2.1. This plugins have errors and have no support.

**What I would like to ask about:**

1. Does 1. plugin support Wifi direct?
2. Do you think That I should buy 2. plugin and try to fix it and hopefully I can find a problem and it will work?
3. Do you know some better or "any" solution how to solve this problem?

I am interested in any tips and help how to make it work.

Thank you very much for your help!

Jakub Kučera

Comment: WiFi-Direct is just a normal IP connection. After the connection handshake have been executed and the group is formed (which most of that is handled by the Android framework), all you have to do is to send normal TCP data-packages to the correct IP address. Said that, you could use any plugin that will open a listening port on the master device and can send data to that port on the slaves devices. But be careful, I doubt you'll be able to connect to that many devices at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After research I have realised a working solution!

Unity Asset Store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/kr/#!/content/53955

Video of usage: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9GaiKCre3w&feature=youtu.be)

**Plugin I have tested on a few Android devices and it works for Wifi Direct with no connection to internet.**

This plugin supports  much more than that for example:

- TCP
- Client / Server
- Complete C# 2.0 native
- Stand alone library (DLL)
- Multi-Thread
- Event Driven
- Support [Binary/Json] message data
- Log Server & MySQL Sample Code

**New Feature**

- Unreliable UDP
- MNF Server based WinFrom without MySql

I hope it helps somebody else!

And I would like to say thanks to author and his support!

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @ChessMax The closest link I found was this one. Jakub, could you confirm it is the plugin you have used ?
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/wifidirect-plugin-50112  if so, please update the link in your post and also write the name of the package in case it happens in the future again. The one I found is Android only though.

Comment: @ForceMagic no that was not it ... it was this one... https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/53955 (tip use this url pattern and change the id # on the end as needed... has been very usfual for me since Unity changed the urls )